# SolrJ: Should I create a new SolrClient for each request or reuse it?

Tags: solr, solrj

I am writing code for indexing and retrieving from Solr using SolrJ client.

Here is my POC;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient;

public class TestSolrService {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            SolrServerException {
        new TestSolrService().test();
    }

    public void test() throws IOException, SolrServerException {

        SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr/");

        Test test = new Test();
        test.setId("3");
        test.name="TEST";
        Child c = new Child();
        c.flag = 1;
        c.id = "1";
        test.setChild(c);
        client.addBean("test", test, 10);

        client.close();

    }

    public class Child {
        @Field
        public String id;
        @Field("flag_l")
        public int flag;
    }

    public class Test {

        @Field
        private String id;

        @Field("name")
        private String name;

        @Field(child = true)
        private Child child;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Child getChild() {
            return child;
        }

        public void setChild(Child child) {
            this.child = child;
        }

    }
}
```

I am not sure if I should create a new client and do operation or keep one client and use it whenever there is a new request.
While writing above code, eclipse warned for closing client.

Please suggest which approach to go with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is traditional usecase of handling connections. You can use a factory class, may be a singleton, and maintain the connection there.

Also it is recommended to use Load balancer solrserver piece.